# How to add Listview as footer in listview in android?

Tags: android

I have Mainactivity which contain listview with some item and I want to add another listview in that listview as footer.How can I add this

Answer (score 0):

```
 // Create a List from String Array elements


 final List<String> tests = new ArrayList<String>(Arrays.asList(test));
// Create an ArrayAdapter from List
final ArrayAdapter<String> arrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>
        (this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, tests);

// DataBind ListView with items from ArrayAdapter
lv.setAdapter(arrayAdapter);

btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        // Add new Items to List
        tests.add("abc");
        tests.add("def");
        /*
            notifyDataSetChanged ()
                Notifies the attached observers that the underlying
                data has been changed and any View reflecting the
                data set should refresh itself.
         */
        arrayAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
    }
});
```

for more http://android--code.blogspot.in/2015/08/android-listview-add-items.html

Comment: This is not an answer. Please read the question properly before you answer.

Answer (score 0):

Its not recommended to add a `ListView` as a footer of another `ListView`. You might consider making a list of objects containing both list and pass the list to your Adapter.

So if you merge two lists in a common format, you need to be tricky for the layout selection for each item in your list. Let me show you an example of a common class.

```
public class CommonClass {
    // Set null values initially.
    private ClassA mFirstListClass = null;
    private ClassB mSecondListClass = null;
}
```

Now take an `ArrayList` of this object to pass it to your Adapter. In your `bindView` check if the item is a `ClassA` object or `ClassB` object (as you can easily determine them by checking which object is null) and then set proper action.

I think for these kinds of problems `RecyclerView` is better. Its very simple to implement and you can find the [implementation document here](https://developer.android.com/training/material/lists-cards.html).